# Netsuite Past Due Reminder using SuiteScript

Tags: netsuite

The script is complete! Thanks for all those who replied :)

/*
* Author: Laura Micek
* Date: 5-13-15
* Purpose: This script creates a saved search in order to pull the information needed to send out an email to alert customers that
* their account is past due. The saved searched makes sure that the customer is 11 days or more past due, checks to see if they are
* exempt from past due reminders, and that their account balance is greater than 1. Once the saved search runs, it will loop thru the
* customers that meet these requirements and it will use the days past due to determine if an email needs to be sent. An email will 
* only be sent if the days past due are equal to 11 or if the days past due minus 11, modded by 8 equals 0 which means that it has
* been 8 days since the last notification.
*/

```
function email_late_customers(type) {

//variables
var send_from = 22730; // Internal ID of NS User

//setup filters and result columns for a customer saved search
var filters = new Array();
filters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('daysoverdue',null,'greaterthanorequalto',11);
filters[1] = new nlobjSearchFilter('custentitypastdueremind',null,'is', 'F');
filters[2] = new nlobjSearchFilter('balance',null,'greaterthan', 1);
var columns = new Array();
columns[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('internalid');
columns[1] = new nlobjSearchColumn('email');
columns[2] = new nlobjSearchColumn('daysoverdue');

//run saved search and loop thru results
var customers = nlapiSearchRecord('customer',null,filters,columns);
for (var i = 0; customers != null && i < customers.length; i++) {

    //grab all the customer data
    var this_customer = customers[i];
    var cust_id = this_customer.getValue('internalid');
    var send_to = this_customer.getValue('email');
    var getpastduedays = this_customer.getValue('daysoverdue');

    //this is the check to see if the amount of days is over 11 to see if another email needs to be sent.
    if(getpastduedays > 11) {
    var checkPastDue = (getpastduedays - 11) % 8;
    }

    /* 
    if the above checkPastDues evaluates to zero then it has been 8 days since the last notification, this is the other condition to send an email. The first being that the customer is 11 days past due.
    */
    if(getpastduedays  == 11 || checkPastDue == 0) {

            //email subject
            var subject = 'Your Account is Past Due';

            // create body text
            var body = 'Hello, \r\r';
            body += ' This is a reminder that your account is currently past due. Attached is a current detailed aging of your account for your reference.\r\r ';
            body += '  Can you please review and let me know the status of payment?\r\r';
            body += '  Your prompt attention to this matter would be greatly appreciated. If you have any questions reguarding this account, please ';
            body += ' contact us as soon as possible. Any questions or invoice copy requests can be email to ar@doubleradius.com.\r\r';
            body += ' If payment has been recently been made, please accept our thanks and ignore this reminder.\r\r';
            body += 'Thank You!\r\r';

            //setup filters and result columns for a transaction saved search
            var filters = new Array();
            filters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('status',null,'is', 'CustInvc:A');
            filters[1] = new nlobjSearchFilter('type',null,'is', 'CustInvc');
            filters[2] = new nlobjSearchFilter('email',null,'is', send_to);
            filters[3] = new nlobjSearchFilter('mainline',null,'is', 'T');
            var columns = new Array();
            columns[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('internalid');

            //run saved search and loop thru results
            var transactions = nlapiSearchRecord('transaction',null,filters,columns);
            var invoices = [];
                for (var i = 0; transactions != null && i < transactions.length; i++) {
                    //grab all the transaction data
                    var this_transaction = transactions[i];
                    invoices[i] = this_transaction.getValue('internalid');      
                }

            //print the statement to a PDF file object
            var attachment = [];
            for (var i = 0; invoices != null && i < invoices.length; i++) {
            attachment[i] = nlapiPrintRecord('TRANSACTION',invoices[i],'DEFAULT',null);
            }

            //send the PDF as an attachment
            nlapiSendEmail(send_from,/*send_to*/ 'lauram@doubleradius.com', subject, body, null, null, null, attachment);

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to use a Scheduled Script you will need to collect the records you want to inspect. If these are Customer records then be sure to setup searchFilters and  searchColumns to come back and then collect the results.

```
// set Customer record filters and columns to return 
var filters = new Array();
filters.push( new nlobjSearchFilter('isActive', null, 'is', 'F') );
filters.push( new nlobjSearchFilter('someotherfield', null, 'isempty') );

var cust_cols = new Array();
cust_cols.push( new nlobjSearchColumn('companyname') );
cust_cols.push( new nlobjSearchColumn('someotherfield') );
// now get the records that fit your filters and return the cols specified
overdue_customers = nlapiSearchRecord('customer', null, searchfilter, columns);
```

I generally like to move my content/body creating code into separate functions but it's really not that important depending on how complicated your script is. For instance I have a couple of scripts that do a lot of processing that have to send some information on a record by record basis but also sends "digest" type emails to others. Think customers and account managers. While it was a pain to set up everything up to handle both cases having a email content generating function was much saner and easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need scripting to achieve this simple requirement. All you need is a saved search and a workflow. The key thing here is you need to come up with the right criteria on your saved search. Once you have the right saved search you set your workflow's Initiation to run on Scheduled and choose the frequency. Use the Send Email action to send the email to the customers and you are good to go.

Also, from the saved search you can join the customer record to the Messages Field so you will have the ability to check when was the last email sent.

You might also need a Email Template.

Answer (score 0):

Though there are many approaches you could use for this, I think your scheduled script approach will work just fine. You can make the logic for identifying which emails to send by offloading the 8-day calculation to your search filters, instead of manually trying to compute. I would have a filter in my search of something like:

```
new nlobjSearchFilter('custentity_dayssincelastemailed', null, 'before', 'previousOneWeek');
```

See the Help article titled *Search Date Filters* for more details on what you can do with Dates in filters.

After that, I believe you should be able to create an Email Template and utilize that in your code to set the title and the boilerplate of the email body.

Where I'm a little less certain, and what may be more difficult for you, is your A/R Aging attachment. Not sure I've worked with attaching statements.